# Get average from array

Tags: php, sql, average

It looks like I can get the average of the whole array but not of each item in a array. I would like to avoid some loop.
I use the function AVG() for it.

```
$sql_statement = "SELECT AVG(answer) AS averageanswer
                FROM answer2
                WHERE question_id
                IN(".implode(",", $qid).")
                AND answer <= 5
            ";

$dblink = mysql_connect($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword);
mysql_select_db($DB,$dblink);
$qry = mysql_query($sql_statement,$dblink);

while($averageanswer=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $average[] = round($averageanswer['averageanswer']);
}
```

When I print the array this is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 )
```

Did someone experience the same problem before or does someone know the solution for me? All tips are welcome!

Comment: What result are you expecting?  We need to see the data in the DB.  '4' could be a perfectly valid average.

Comment: The average of each item in the array $qid is 4. It is true that the output I get is 4. But I do not want 1 output of 4. My output should look like Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 [2] => 4 [3] => 4 ).

Comment: What is "it"? What are you trying to achieve? Your code is broken so we can't figure out what you want to do from it.

Comment: BTW database don't have "arrays".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are wanting the Average results, per question. In which case:

```
$sql_statement = "SELECT AVG(answer) AS averageanswer
                FROM answer2
                WHERE question_id
                IN(".implode(",", $qid).")
                AND answer <= 5
                GROUP BY question_id
            ";

$dblink = mysql_connect($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword);
mysql_select_db($DB,$dblink);
$qry = mysql_query($sql_statement,$dblink);

while($averageanswer=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $average[] = round($averageanswer['averageanswer']);
}
```

This will result in one row, per question_id, containing the average of answers for any row with that question_id